# Moving code to another class leads to app crash

Tags: java, android, function, class

I'm creating an Android app and everything seems to be working fine. The problem starts when I try to move some of the code to **another file**, in order to tide things up.

Let's say that the app has a spinner and a button. Pressing the button reads the current selected string of the Spinner and presents it with a Toast. So the code is:

```
Spinner spinnerOmadas=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOmadas);
String omada = spinnerOmadas.getSelectedItem().toString();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), omada,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If I keep this code in the onClick function of the button in the main activity, everything works. I want to move it to another file since I will be adding more code to it.

So I create a file **buttonCalculation.java** with the following code:

```
package com.test.example;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class buttonCalculation extends MainActivity {

    public void calculate(){

        Spinner spinnerOmadas=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOmadas);
        String t1= spinnerOmadas.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

and in the onClick method of the main activity I do this:

```
buttonCalculation b1 = new buttonCalculation();
b1.calculate();
```

There is no error according to Android Studio in my approach, but when I run the app and press the button, it crashes.

Is there something that I have to declare to be able to find the objects of the main Activity?

Comment: use instance for it.

Comment: This shouldn't be how you tidy things up. If anything you're making it more complex and harder to maintain.

Comment: Hey man. I took the effort of reading your log and pasting the error in your question. You reverted that ? What is up with your refusal to show us your error ?

Comment: What do you mean? What refusal? You asked for my logcat and i posted it. @shantanu 's answer worked. The problem was that the layout wasn't defined anywhere and couldn't be accessed without being passed to the new class/method.

Comment: Your log contained: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825) at com.duk3r.prisma.buttonCalculation.calculate(buttonCalculation.java:14) at com.duk3r.prisma.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53) and so on... If you would leave that in the question (like I had added that for you) instead of a 6000 lines logcat, then that would have been the perfect question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the function `findViewById()` as you do not have any layout defined in your `buttonCalculation` class. Therefore you have to pass it as a parameter.

```
public class ButtonCalculation { //I don't find any reason to extend MainActivity here

    //also you need a constructor (except if you are using a static method)
    public void ButtonCalculation (){

    }

    public void calculate(ViewGroup root, Context context){

        Spinner spinnerOmadas=(Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOmadas);
        String t1= spinnerOmadas.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Toast.makeText(context, t1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

And in your MainActivity

```
final ViewGroup root= (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
ButtonCalculation b1 = new ButtonCalculation ();
b1.calculate(root, getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I had only extended MainActivity since i was hoping i could be able to resolve the spinner and everything else from the mainactivity's xml easier.

Tried your code, the only error it gives me is on "getApplicationContext()". It cannot resolve it.

Comment: Small Edit, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

First declare the spinner button as a global variable in the **MainActivity:**

```
protected Spinner spinner;
```

then in the `onCreate()` Method of **MainActivity** initialize it.

```
spinnerOmadas=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOmadas);
```

and then you can use it in your **buttonCalculation** class as :

```
String t1= spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```